# Twilio - Fetching list of user's incoming phone numbers

Tags: twilio

We have implemented a connect app, and we are  trying to show a list of users' incoming phone numbers, but we are not able to fetch this list and we always get empty list, I have understood the following about the API -

When a user connects his account with a Twilio button, then a new sub-account is created for this client app, and the sid for this new sub account is sent in the callback url. for exmaple - lets say the account SID is `111111`, and when this account authorizes a connect app, then a new sub account is created with new SID, lets say it is `2222222`, this new SID is then sent in the callback url of the connect app.

The issue I am facing is that this new SID always returns an empty list of user's phone numbers, so I need some way to authorize the connect app with the actual user SID (111111), can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to port your numbers to the sub accounts for them to be used as you have requested.
To port the numbers, you need to login to the sub account and then go to porting page.

Once a number is ported, it can be completely used in the sub Account.